Unboxing a possibly null value on struct in C# - Looking for alternative solution
For the following code, I receive the warning Unboxing a possibly null value. (CS8605) in VS Code with C# Dev Kit:

Original code with warning:
// Originally a struct
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private struct POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO {
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING Name;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING DnsDomainName;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING DnsForestName;
    public GUID DomainGuid;
    public IntPtr pSID;
}

// Additional code removed for simplicity

resultQueryPolicy = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(
    policyHandle,
    POLICY_INFORMATION_CLASS.PolicyDnsDomainInformation,
    out IntPtr infoStructure
);

winErrorCode = LsaNtStatusToWinError(resultQueryPolicy);

if (winErrorCode == 0) {

    POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO domain = (POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(infoStructure, typeof(POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO));

// Additional code removed for simplicity
}

Current working solution:
// I changed the struct to a class
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private class POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO {
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING Name;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING DnsDomainName;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING DnsForestName;
    public GUID DomainGuid;
    public IntPtr pSID;
}

// Additional code removed for simplicity

resultQueryPolicy = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(
    policyHandle,
    POLICY_INFORMATION_CLASS.PolicyDnsDomainInformation,
    out IntPtr infoStructure
);

winErrorCode = LsaNtStatusToWinError(resultQueryPolicy);

if (winErrorCode == 0) {

    // I applied T?
    POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO? domain = (POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO?)Marshal.PtrToStructure(infoStructure, typeof(POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO));

// Additional code removed for simplicity
}

I'm looking for an alternative solution (hopefully simple) without having to convert the struct to a class.  Is this possible?

You should just have to check the return for null and make a decision if it is such as throwing an exception. Or if you know you'll never get a null object back then can ignore the warning #pragma warning disable CS8605 above the line and #pragma warning restore CS8605 below it.

Why don't you just use the generic version Marshal.PtrToStructure<POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO>(infoStructure)

As per Charlieface's comment, using the generic version Marshal.PtrToStructure<POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO>(infoStructure) worked.
Alternative solution
// Reverted back to struct
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private struct POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO {
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING Name;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING DnsDomainName;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING DnsForestName;
    public GUID DomainGuid;
    public IntPtr pSID;
}

// Additional code removed for simplicity

resultQueryPolicy = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(
    policyHandle,
    POLICY_INFORMATION_CLASS.PolicyDnsDomainInformation,
    out IntPtr infoStructure
);

winErrorCode = LsaNtStatusToWinError(resultQueryPolicy);

if (winErrorCode == 0) {

    // Using generic version which works without any warnings
    POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO domain = Marshal.PtrToStructure<POLICY_DNS_DOMAIN_INFO>(infoStructure);

// Additional code removed for simplicity
}


Don't forget to free the infoStructure buffer using LsaFreeMemory in a finally

@Charlieface Yes, I have LsaFreeMemory() in my code.  I just didn't include it my example for simplicity.
